# Make a dynamic URL in retrofit

Tags: java, android

**I want url like this**

*baseurl/dealer/index.php?r=rest/packInfo*

**I am doing like this**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/dealer/index.php?r=rest/{method}") 
void getDealersPacks(@Path("method") String method,
            @Field("cd_dealer_id") String cd_dealer_id,
            @Field("country_code") String country_code,
            @Field("business_type")String business_type);
```

**And i am getting error**

URL query string "r=rest/{method}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Comment: Try using an if statement with a condition you want a dynamic URL

Answer (score 0):

You are passing @Path annotation for query parameter.

You can do it this way :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/dealer/index.php") 
void getDealersPacks( @Query("r") String query, @Field("cd_dealer_id") String cd_dealer_id, @Field("country_code") String country_code, @Field("business_type") String business_type);
```

Now , pass "rest/packInfo" or any other dynamic value in query parameter, it will work.

Hope , it helps !!

Comment: @vineet sharma  kindly accept answer if it helps you ....don't keep any question open unnecassarily.